# java use .png file in .jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, resources

i have simple application with structure like:

[image: this]

And i want to use images(`.png`) in my program from `.jar` file (after i will compile it). 
I have read about `getResourceAsStream` and how i should to define name of `.png` file so that it would work after `.jar` compilation.

But it doesn't work in `.jar`, it works only when i starts appplication throught IDE(*Intellij Idea*).
Can someone help me with this?

**Details:**

```
ImageView imgY = new ImageView(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("Y.png")));
ImageView imgN = new ImageView(new Image(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("N.png")));
```

In IDE i have set folder which contain `.png`-images as `Resources` [(look screenshot)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM90K.png)

Sorry, i can't add screenshots - the reputation not enought.
**Upd:**
I forgot to say, that after compilation `.jar`-file contain my `.png` files, but when i run it, i gave error:
[screen again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twLGQ.png)

Comment: Hi, have  you tried : this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Y.png") (the / is important) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the second problem, how did you create the jar? (are you using maven, IntelliJ, other)

did you doubleclick it to launch?

is the main class set in the manifest (no, because the manifest is missing)?

can you set English as the language in Winrar before taking a screenshot

Comment: I have maked `jar` using Intellij standart compiller (as i know it ant), using menu `Artifacts`.  About `MANIFEST` i thought that it is not needed, because there is only one class... If i will create it, what have to happen?

Comment: I don't really know much about Ant and IntelliJ but you should be able to set you main class somewhere so that javaw knows what to start when double clicking, then an extra file should be included in the jar - the manifest file - which is a text file, more about manifest files here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/defman.html

Comment: a manifest file is used when you double click on the jar to execute it (can also include a list of dependencies - not in your case) (can include other info like build data/user/java version/etc), the manifest file is normally not used in an IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ; it's not related to finding the images but to starting the application outside the IDE

Answer (score 1):

this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Y.png")

the / is important (I could not comment on your comment - needed 50 reputation)

in an IDE like IntelliJ the png is still a file and not included in a jar, this should work both ways

yuo can also use

this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("Y.png")

Comment: i have tried to use forward slash like `'/Y.png'`. In IDE it works (as whithout slash), but in `.jar` it doesn't work anyway

Comment: The directory must be in the classpath of the JAR : if you put the icons in src folder, it should work

Comment: without starting / (absolute path) it adds the packagename of this.getClass() in front of it (relative path) ; there may be a problem that your main class should be in a package (folder)

Comment: @Tuco i have put it in `src` folder, and compile jar. In IDE it works, in jar - no

Answer (score 0):

@JurgenDeLandsheer's answer worked for me. Trying getting the image through the method:

this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Y.png")